# Submitting a Form using Mechanize (PubChem)

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to write a chemical property scraper for PubChem. I am pretty new to mechanize, and just programming in general, so I got stuck on how to submit the form for this website: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/.

br.submit() is producing an error (it just says httperror_seek_wrapper), and I am unsure on how to proceed from there. I have tried targeting the button that actually submits with the following:

```
 def pubchem():
    br = Browser()
    br.open("https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/")
    br.select_form(nr=0)
    form = br.form
    form['term'] = "74-82-8"
    form.click(id='go')
```

But that doesn't seem to work either. I would love some help on where to look for the answer, or alternative method for submitting this form.

I'll be super grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data from PubChem with their service [PUG REST](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pug_rest/PUG_REST.html)

A simple example:

```
import urllib2
import json

def get(url):
    req = urllib2.Request(url)
    response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()

pugrest = 'http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/rest/pug/compound/name/'
cmpd = 'methane'
prop ='/property/MolecularFormula,MolecularWeight,CanonicalSMILES,InChI,IUPACNam/JSON'

data = get(pugrest+cmpd+prop)
print data
```

This will give you this json:

{ "PropertyTable": { "Properties": [ { "CID": 297, "MolecularFormula": "CH4", "MolecularWeight": 16.04246, "CanonicalSMILES": "C", "InChI": "InChI=1S/CH4/h1H4", "IUPACName": "methane" } ] } }